# Uncheck radio button custom control in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-controls, radio-button, html-helper

I want to create a radio button custom control in my ASP MVC application. I am using HTML Helpers for this (I hope it is the right way). I want to know if there is a way to make the radio button unchecked when clicked.
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are creating one single radio button and you set it up to be check, you will not be able of unchecking. For that you need to create more than one item which belongs to the same radio group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way to make the radio button unchecked when clicked.

That's a very weird requirement and you probably should be using checkboxes instead of radio buttons, but anyway, it is possible with javascript. If we suppose that the radio button is checked initially and you want to uncheck it when clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_radio_button').click(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

But really, that's very weird. Radio buttons normally work by having them in groups: you have a couple of radio buttons and you can check only one in the group. So by selecting a different radio button in the group you are unchecking the current one.

Checkboxes on the other hand are not grouped. You can check/uncheck their values by clicking on them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know it's weired that's why I'm posting this question but that's what my boss wants. Your answer sounds great I will try it.